# How can I map a DATETIME column to Date object using JPA and DB2

Tags: java, date, jpa, db2, spring-data

I'm trying to query a DB2 database and mapping a `DATEIME` colum to `Date` using *Java* but I'm getting this  error:

DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-181, SQLSTATE=22007, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.21.29

> Short Description: THE STRING REPRESENTATION OF A DATETIME VALUE IS
>   NOT A VALID DATETIME VALUE C
>
> The string representation of a datetime is not in the acceptable range
>   or is not in the correct format. The proper ranges for datetime values
>   are as follows: Table 2. Range of datetime values Datetime Numeric
>   Range Years 0001 to 9999 Months 1 to 12 Days April, June, September,
>   November (months 4, 6, 9, 11) 1 to 30 February (month 2) 1 to 28 (Leap
>   year 1 to 29) January, March, May, July, August, October, December
>   (months 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12) 1 to 31 Hours 0 to 24 (If hour is 24,
>   other parts of time values are zeroes. If hour is USA, maximum hour is
>   12.) Minutes 0 to 59 Seconds 0 to 59 Microseconds 0 to 999999 System action: The statement cannot be executed. Programmer response: Check
>   whether the value is within the valid range and is in the proper
>   format. Refer to Chapter 2 of DB2 SQL Reference for information on
>   string data formats.

First I'm convert a LocalDate to Date

```
public static Date convertLocalDateToDate(LocalDate date) {
    return  Date.from(date.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
}
```

Second I'm using a Specification API

```
public static Specification<MyEntity> dataUse(Date dataUse){
    return (root, query, builder) -> builder.equal(root.get("myDate"), dataUse);
}
```

My field within the Entity is map as

```
@Column(name="DT_EX_MOVI_IN")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date myDate;
```

And final when I try to execute the query

```
repository.findAll(query);
```

I get the error error `DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-181, SQLSTATE=22007, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.21.29`

Someone Could help me?

Thanks

Comment: In My DataBase the Date that I want to compare was created as Date

Comment: Are you using the java.sql.Date class or java.util.Date ?, Why don't you  map the column directly to a LocalDate ?

Comment: The problemn isn't when I get data of DB for my Object Java. The problem is when I execute the query.

The Problem: MY DB2 has a collum map as DATE, not DATETIME. When I try to execute query comparing with Object JAVA DATE with collumn in my DB2 with DATETIME is OK I can return data but when I try to execute my Object JAVA DATE with collumn in my DB2 with DATE I get error DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-181, SQLSTATE=22007, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.21.29.

I have alredy tried to execute query with other types Object Java of type DATE such as DATE, DateLocal, LocalDateTime but I haven't success.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. I read documentation of DB2 https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/java/src/tpc/imjcc_rjvjdata.html

And my solution was map my object with java.sql.Date.

Thank you very much for all that tried help me!

Comment: Because of it I asked you whether you were using java.sql.Date or java.util.Date

Comment: Thank you @EduardoEljaiek because your comment I went to serach how map the types DB2 to Java and I found that doc. I really thank you for your attention.